# i tried to push struct in fixed array through my function but dont know how

Tags: windows, blockchain, solidity, remix

i first pushed my struct of clothes through my function **addclothes** in an dynamic array and it worked easily , but dont know how to do it with static arrays can someone please help someone. i beleive it is easy to figure it out

```
struct clothes {
    string name;
    string color;
}

clothes[5] public Clothes;

function addCloth(string calldata _name, string calldata _color) public {
    Clothes.push(clothes(_name,_color));
}
```

i did it pretty easily before it the code is here but with dynamic array

```
'struct clothes {
    string name;
    string color;
}

clothes[] public Clothes;

function addCloth(string calldata _name, string calldata _color) public {
    Clothes.push(clothes(_name,_color));
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push to dynamic arrays because they are dynamic. Pushing allocates memory for a new slot on the blockchain for the array slot, and appends a new element to that array.

Static arrays don't support pushing because when you initialize them you have to define their size, which means that you'll allocate the memory for those slots when you deploy the contract, and it doesn't allow you to modify its size nor append new elements.

So, instead of pushing, you'll have to iterate and set those slots.

In my example I use a counter to iterate over the array and give them a value.

```js
contract Cloth {
    struct Clothes {
        string name;
        string color;
    }

    Clothes[5] public clothes;
    uint counter = 0;

    function addCloth(string calldata _name, string calldata _color) public {
        require(counter < 5, "Can't add more clothes. Limit of the array reached.");
        clothes[counter] = Clothes(_name,_color);
        counter++;
    }
}
```